# What is a possible reason for an L-1011 wing fuel tank overflow?

Tags: safety, fuel-systems, lockheed-tristar

I was on a TWA Charter flight from Boston to Montego Bay Jamaica in 1989.  During pushback from the gate, the right wing began to leak jetfuel (like gallons pouring out of the wing).  They stopped the pushback and the first officer rushed back to take a look.  We didn't evacuate, the fire trucks came, and after the spill was cleaned up on the tarmac, we departed without incident.  Curious if this was a typical mishap on the L1011 or if someone could provide any possible reason for this to occur.  I couldn't believe we were allowed to depart without a detailed inspection.